# Is there a command that allows you to do something to all entities other than yourself in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to know for a datapack I'm making

Comment: Have you looked for answers yourself before asking here? Arqade works best when you share your past research or trials.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I have and I kept getting answers for bedrock or 1.12

Comment: What commands have you tried? Put that in your question.

Comment: I haven't tried any because I didn't know where to start.

Comment: Besides, "do something" is way too vague. Can you describe in detail what you want to achieve, what you have tried, and what questions you found were similar (even if for another version of Minecraft)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like:

```
@e[distance=0.001..]
```

This selects all entities farther than 0.001 meters from you.